# Generate a string generator (constant associative array)

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

There is a finite set of unique strings and a limited key space. One key corresponds to one string value and a function must exist to perform the resolution. There is no need to support other associative array methods except lookup. Looking up a key without a value leads to undefined behavior.

I would like to find out is it possible (and has it been achieved) to solve the task by generating lookup function code. That is for every existing key there would be a unique code path, which collects the target string character after character. For example, for strings "mate", "date" and "crate" the common "ate" ending can be resolved by following the same code path.

So far all my Google-fu has led to nothing. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called a [Perfect Hash Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function). If you have access to a linux system it likely already has a program called [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) installed that, given a set of strings will generate the C code for such a function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I suppose I was not very careful formulating my requirements. I want a tool to generate me a function that will store relation between unique numeric ID and unique string and will return strings given the ID. I was thinking about generating a giant switch and then letting compiler optimize it. But is there a better way?

Comment: from gperf home page: `GNU gperf is highly customizable. There are options for generating C or C++ code, for emitting switch statements or nested ifs instead of a hash table, and for tuning the algorithm employed by gperf.`